# Power App Form Autofill Text Input from SharePoint List

Tags: list, list-form, powerapp

I am tryiing to auto populate text boxes in my power aps based on sharepoint list datta, for some reason when I put this code into the update box I get this error:
[image]
[image]
Here's the naming convention for the drop down so I don't think hat is the reason:
[image]

In my dropdown that I am using to deterring the information I have this code for the items property:

```
Distinct('Form AutoFill Fields', PRO_SPEC_NUM)
```

In the data card update property I am trying to put:

```
DataCardValue3.Selected.Result
```

And to auto-populate one of the text fields, in the Default property I put:

```
If(
       SharePointForm1.Mode = FormMode.New,
       LookUp('Form AutoFill Fields', PRO_SPEC_NUM = DataCardValue3.Selected.Result, 'Welding Process'),
       Parent.Default
   )
```

Comment: Try using only `DataCardValue3.Selected`, let me know if this works. Also, auto-populate should work for your text field using the same formula you provided in question.

Comment: It unfortunately did not work. Does it have something to do with the the settings for variable "DataCardValue3" This seems to be where the issue is stemming

Comment: I added a photo of the error I keep getting